# unable to get my RouteProvider working as well as the controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, route-provider

### Issue

---

I will split the issue into two different parts. Firstly, I am trying to create a one page application with the main html page being *index.html*.

In this page I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="aceTracker">
<head>

<script src="scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controller/controller.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<link href="styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="loginController">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then i have created a partial page that looks like:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="login" ng-controller="loginController">
    <div class="row">
            <form ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter'}" name="loginForm" ng-submit="" autocomplete="off" class="text-center col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" style="padding: 300px 50px 0px 50px ;">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img src="../images/473d5e6a.canvs_logo_white.svg" style="padding-bottom:30px;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" ng-model="" placeholder="Email" class="login">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <input id="password" type="password" ng-model="" placeholder="Password" class="login">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="login-button" ng-click="Login()">
                        <span>Login</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

            </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in the Javascript i have a file called *app.js* which looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('aceTracker', ['ngAnimate','ngRoute']);


app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

// route for the home page
.when('/index.html', { templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', controller: 'loginController'})

// route for the about page
.when('/about.htmll', { templateUrl: 'pages/about.html', controller: 'aboutController' })

});
```

When i load up my index.html page the partial that i want to load is *login.html* this does not seem to be working?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what your app doing is the following. If you load www.host.com/yoursite/index.html, then you load your application with route '/'.

To go to your index.html route the url would be something like: www.host.com/yoursite/#/index.html

So, to make it work, just change '/index.html' route to '/' route

```
$routeProvider

// route for the home page
.when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', controller: 'loginController'})

// route for the about page
.when('/about', { templateUrl: 'partials/about.html', controller: 'aboutController' })
```

You may also add a default route, so that nobody will get to the partially-rendered view by mistake. I'd suggest you to look at this example of how routes are defined:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Also, I'd recommend looking at the following alternative, whenever you will fill that angular native routing is not enough for your needs:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Thanks for your help this seemed to work. Quick question though, some of my controls are not appearing from my partial HTML. Any ideas?

Comment: "some" is a bit too vague. Best starting point is to examine your html in developers tools in chrome, for example. There you can see what exactly is being rendered and you can also see styles that are applies for each element. You may find explanation for missing elements there.